# MONO 3.2 for Windows / Linux - Missing?

Tags: mono

Looking for a download to MONO Runtime 3.2 but I just can find this for Mac.
See [HERE](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.2#New_in_Mono_3.2)

Are there no releases for Linux/Windows ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Are there no releases for **Linux**?

The [tarball](http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-3.2.0.tar.bz2) is all you need to use/install Mono in Linux.
If what you want is that your favourite distro imports this version of Mono into its packaging system (e.g.: apt-get), then you would need to ask in the forums, mailing lists or other online resources about that distro.

> Are there no releases for **Windows**?

First, I will ask you another question, are you sure do you really need Mono for Windows? For most use cases, Windows already bundles .NET into the last versions. Furthermore, Mono for Windows is not a top priority platform for the Mono team and may **lack features** or have **worse performance** than on Linux/Mac. Therefore Mono for windows is only really useful for [certain uncommon scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751648/whats-the-point-of-mono-on-windows#answer-758392).

If you're really interested in those uncommon use cases, then keep bugging Mono maintainers in their forums, mailing lists or IRC, to remind them to package it (it's not really a priority anymore since this platform is not something they target with [their commercial offerings](http://www.xamarin.com)).

**UPDATE**: A Xamarin employee [stated](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2013-August/050203.html) that the installer would be available when version 3.2.3 is released, and they complied with their promise because 3.2.3 has been released and the windows installer is available in the download page.

Comment: Thank you, I've just seen the downlaod page [link](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html) without releases for Win etc.
And regarding Mono running on Windows - I thought it would be easier to debug / test when I develop on Windows, therefore I was looking for a current release, but still cannot find any.
And is this tarball officially released ?

So in the end I think it's better to post on Mono website directly.

Comment: Makes things more clear - [Mono 3.0 is out](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Oct-22.html)

Comment: that tarball is official yes (you can reach to it by clicking on the "Mono sources" link inside the download page that you linked

Comment: Thank you - now I know to get further releases (>3.x) from GitHub directly as you can see in my previous comment.

Comment: I don't recommend getting tarballs from github, they have some inconveniences that the official tarballs don't have

Comment: @nhaberl: Where does [that announcement](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2012/Oct-22.html) make anything clearer? The only mentions of "Windows" that I could find are in the comments; one thread talks about how F# is not going to be bundled for Windows (not stating anything on the Mono Framework Win-installer itself), and the others are by more confused Windows developers who are looking in vain for the Windows download ... which I still couldn't find, not even [here](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/).

Comment: Actually, the latest Windows installer available seems to be for [Mono 3.0.10](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.0.10/windows-installer/).

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: ..._We are trying to reduce our inventory of pending work and get new features to everyone faster. **This means that our "master" branch will remain stable from now on**, and that large projects will instead be developed in branches that are regularly landed into our master branch..._
How to install tarballs on Windows -> http://www.mono-project.com/Compiling_Mono_on_Windows

Comment: @nhaberl: I don't understand how that statement is related. Even if the "master" branch is version 2.10.* for now, "to remain stable" usually means something different than "to cease development" (i.e. adding new versions eventually). Likewise, "master branch" usually has another meaning than "binary release". As for the compilation link, thanks, found that - unfortunately, that is not really suitable for non-programmers who formerly had the advantage of choice between two runtimes on Windows; now they are more or less bound to one particular runtime again based on their OS.

Comment: We do need Mono for Windows. And it's very pity that the team stop publishing Mono releases for Windows.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper You are right - for non programmers it's a pitty that no windows installer is supported for current versions. But I think that's ok because there is almost any .NET runtime available which should match to the target application.
So in the end the only use case for installing MONO on Windows is for development purposes - where you (almost) have programming skills in that way you can install MONO with the given tarballs.

Comment: @nhaberl: I kind of disagree, as I thought one of the advantages *and* goals of Mono was to provide users with a choice and an alternative to the official .NET runtime. But that is not a discussion this site is suitable for.

Comment: I have to agree that this is very confusing.  My company has a huge investment in .NET and are interested in moving to Linux.  From the looks of the download page, one can only deduce that not only is Windows only supported up to v2.10, neither is Linux... Distributions for all platform is available for v2.10, but for v.3.#, distributions are only available for Mac OS X.  Very confusing.

Comment: @kellyb: Linux is as confusing as its ecosystem is; if there were less distributions , there would be less need to package software so many times, saving tons of duplicated effort, and this would make the distros (namely, their volunteers) more capable of dealing with software upgrades. Another solution is meta-packaging software like Open Build Service, but unfortunately only one distro has adopted it AFAIK. If you want to improve anything about how confusing this is, there is no other way than contributing your 2cents of effort to change things (in the Linux ecosystem, not in the Mono side)