# How to install mono 3.3.0 in window xp?

Tags: mono

I have a dedicated server with Ubuntu 12.04 and mono 3.3.0 and xsp4,
I would like to use mono 3.3.0 on my WIN XP, but unfortunately mono official web site only available for mono version 2.x something. this is the mono official web site.
http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html

I have tried search on google, but all article are explaning about installation mono 3.3.0 on Ubuntu, not for Window.

Any idea how to install mono 3.3.0 and xsp4 on window xp?

Comment: Perhaps using .NET on XP is a better option? Or does it have to be mono?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Yes, it must be use mono, because not all the ext.net function are compatible with mono.I can't use IIS to testing

Comment: possible duplicate of [MONO 3.2 for Windows - Missing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922193/mono-3-2-for-windows-missing)